# How to configure Static IP on iPhone

Tags: wifi, iphone, network

I Want to use wifi on my iphone, Anybody can help me.
I am already using my laptop on the same network through static IP. Please also tell me that Mac address will be used in this situation. The static IP of my laptop is below:

IP Address: 10.10.10.144
Subnet Mask: 255.0.0.0
Default Gateway: 10.10.10.1
Preferred DNS Server: 10.10.10.1

Answer (score 4):

Assuming iOS 6:

- Tap on “Settings” and then tap on “General”
- Tap “Wi-Fi” and look for the network name you are connected to, tap
  the blue (>) arrow next to it
- Tap the “Static” tab and enter network appropriate DHCP/static IP
  information
     Close out of Settings and launch Safari or another network app to confirm connectivity

[image: Example]

---

To see the MAC Address of your iPhone,

- Tap on “Settings” and then tap on “General”
- Tap “About” and look for the "Wi-Fi Address"

Comment: What is supposed to be entered in the Router field, is it Default Gateway?

Comment: What if the WiFi is changed, will iOS remember the static address?